# Font Awesome Icons Won't Work

Tags: shortcode, icon

I do have font awesome installed with my theme.
The icons on my home page was working well before.
I dont know why but the shortcodes of my icons now stopped working.
I do have empty white square instead of the icons. Or nothing at all.
I am not skilled so can please check my site and help me out how to fix this problem?
www.ekn.sinankarabulut.com

Shortcode for an icon is;
[iconbox title="Başarı" icon="star-empty"]Çözüm üretiyoruz...[/iconbox]

You can inspect them from my home page, icons were in the orange boxes.

Thanks for your time...

Comment: Can you please provide a url so we can review the html rendered?

Comment: i though i wrote sorry. url is:  www.ekn.sinankarabulut.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
[iconbox title="Başarı" icon=" fa fa-star"]Çözüm üretiyoruz...[/iconbox]

[iconbox title="Başarı" icon=" fa fa-html5"]Çözüm üretiyoruz...[/iconbox]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your FontAwesome icons is being improperly formatted with the "icons-fa" class. For the second icon block "Kalite", for example, this is wrong:

```
<i class="icons-fa fa-cogs"></i>
```

Change it to this:

```
<i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
```

And then it works.